# Nginx and Redirects

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have `nginx` which I use as proxy towards `Apache` servers.`nginx` listens on `<public_ip>:8087`.

```
server {
    listen       8087;
    server_name  leodev  alias  another.alias;
    location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8089;
       port_in_redirect off;
    }

}
```

The problem happens when the web application (CakePhp) makes a redirect. If the application would redirect to `'/'`, I see in `Network` logs of the Browser a redirect toward  and not towars `<public_ip>:8087`.Since there are no server listening on port :80 the connection timeouts.

With Apache no problem.
Am I missing some config?

Answer (score 0):

`nginx` can modify the redirect from your web application by using the `proxy_redirect` directive.

You may need to experiment before you find the correct configuration, but you can have more than one rule.

Something like this may work:

```
proxy_redirect http://$host/ http://$host:8087/;
```

But it really depends on the exact response from your web application.

Also, not sure why you have `port_in_redirect off;` at that location.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for details.